# Use multiple databases in Strapi v4

Tags: mysql, node.js, sqlite, strapi

I want to modify the file config/database.js to use multiple databases. I need to use sqlite for local and MySQL for dev and prod. Is there any way to do this? I’m using Strapi 4.6.0

This is what I have in `database.js`:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  connection: {
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
      host: env('DATABASE_HOST'),
      port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT'),
      database: env('DATABASE_NAME'),
      user: env('DATABASE_USERNAME'),
      password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
      ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
    },
  },
});
```

but I need to use MySQL only for dev and prod, and use sqlite for local

Answer (score 0):

There's this section in the docs that could assist your use case: https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/optional/environment.html#environment-configurations

Basically, you can create several config files that target different environments following the convention: `./config/env/{environment}/{filename}`.

E.g.

- `./config/env/development/database.js`
- `./config/env/production/database.js`.